# MPEG2 Presentation Time Stamps (PTS) calculation

Tags: c++, video, mpeg2-ts

I have an MPEG2 TS file and now I am interested in extracting PTS information from each picture frame. I know that PTS is described in 33 bits including 3 marker bits. But I don't know how this bitfield can be converted to more understandable form (seconds, milliseconds). Can anybody help me please

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The MPEG2 transport stream clocks (PCR, PTS, DTS) all have units of 1/90000 second.  The PTS and DTS have three marker bits which you need to skip over.  The pattern is always (from most to least significant bit) 3 bits, marker, 15 bits, marker, 15 bits, marker.  The markers must be equal to 1.  In C, removing the markers would work like this:

```
uint64_t v; // this is a 64bit integer, lowest 36 bits contain a timestamp with markers
uint64_t pts = 0;
pts |= (v >> 3) & (0x0007 << 30); // top 3 bits, shifted left by 3, other bits zeroed out
pts |= (v >> 2) & (0x7fff << 15); // middle 15 bits
pts |= (v >> 1) & (0x7fff <<  0); // bottom 15 bits
// pts now has correct timestamp without markers in lowest 33 bits
```

They also have an extension field of 9bits, forming a 42bit integer in which the extension is the least significant bits.  The units for the base+extension are 1/27000000 second.  Many implementations leave the extension as all zeros.

Comment: Hi Alex I,
Long shot here; do you know why the data is stored in this way? I've looked around and I haven't been able to find an answer.

Comment: @jpihl I suspect the markers are there for one of two reasons: (1) to catch all-zero timestamps as being invalid, and (2) to catch bitstreams that are being read or decoded a bit at a time as being invalid when there is a bit offset.  The units of 90000 are chosen so that both 30 fps and 29.97 fps are exact fractions.

Comment: I see, those are both good points, thank you very much! To me it just seemed like it made the spec more complicated for no good reason.

Comment: Actually extension to 27MHz has **PCR** only. **PTS** and **DTS** have units in 90KHz only.
*NOTE:* only [0,299] values used from 9bit of extension (not full range [0,511]).

Answer (score 8):

24hours/day * 60min/hr * 60secs/min *90k/sec (clock) = 7962624000, which needs 33 bits to be represented; You can extract your time from the clock using this info;

Comment: Nice remark. I think the "k" is for 1e3 (not "K"). so 7776000000 still 33bits though.

Comment: does it mean I can get absolute time of day at encoder side from PTS? Just using 00:00:00 as the base?

Comment: @wick No, unfortunately it doesn't mean that.  PTS starts at an arbitrary value, it's not specified in the standard.  Most programs/devices that produce transport streams start at 0 for the beginning of each stream.  They *could* start at the time of day expressed in PTS, but in practice none do that.

Comment: PTS could be combined with PCR to get actual clock at the encoder side, though it is not guaranteed in any way to have any relation to the wall clock :).