# Generate PCR from PTS/DTS

Tags: video, video-streaming, mpeg2-ts, hevc

I have a bitstream of HEVC frames with its associated PTS/DTS and a bitstream of aac frames with its associated PTS/DTS. I don't have a PCR.
I try to mux them in a correct TS at constant bitrate (cbr).

How can I generate the PCR from PTS/DTS informations while respecting the cbr constraint?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606023/mpeg2-presentation-time-stamps-pts-calculation) answer but it's impossible to proceed like that in a cbr bitstream.

Thanks.